Why is "select key" working in bash, but not in zsh?
I'm getting a bad substitution error in this bash script - pointing to the "select key in..." line.
The issues seems to be that I'm running it in a zsh shell (it runs fine in a bash shell). But I thought that the #!/usr/bin/env bash would address this issue. I did quite a few searches, but didn't find an answer to this.
Here's the script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Declare an associative array (hash table)
declare -A DIRS=(
  ["project1"]="$HOME/projects/project1"
  ["project2"]="$HOME/projects/project2"
  ["project3"]="$HOME/projects/project3"
)

# Prompt for the selection
PS3="Please enter your choice (1-${#DIRS[@]}): "

# Display the list of directories
echo "Select a directory to navigate in tmux:"
select key in "${!DIRS[@]}"; do
  if [[ -n "$key" ]]; then
    DIR=${DIRS[$key]}
    echo "Navigating to: $DIR"
    break
  else
    echo "Invalid selection. Please try again."
  fi
done

cd "$DIR"


It works for me, launching from zsh. How are you running the script?

Your interactive shell has no effect on the shell used by a script with a shebang line.

Are you using source scriptname or . scriptname? In that case, the shebang has no effect, since the whole point of that is to execute the script in the current shell. It seems like you would have to do this if you want cd "$DIR" to work. So the script has to be written in zsh syntax.

@Barmar, this was the issue, thanks! I was indeed sourcing it. Ultimately, this snippet will go in a tmux script to navigate to the project directory. (Clearly I'm not a bash guy!) I re-wrote it in zsh, and all is right with the world. Thanks again!
